# Cloud Database problem while connecting thru SSMS

Tags: azure-sql-database, clouddb

I have created a cloud database and was able to connect successfully thru SSMS.
Now I want to create a table in that.

Henceforth after the successful connection ( in am doing thru SSMS) when I am trying to connect to the database i.e. **MyFirstCloudDB** database which is available in the ***Available Databases*** section of SSMS, I am getting the error message " The database MyFirstCloudDB" is not accessible.

What to do now?

EDIT:

I have success accomplished my work.

But what I have done is that after I logged in to my SQL AZURE platform thru SSMs, first I created a database(say myFirstDB). 
Then I logged out. Again I connected and this time Under Options->Connect to Database->I typed myFirstDB and then connected. 
After that I created a table and inserted some values.

*I have included this paras by thinking that if someone like me face the same problem then they can go ahead with this solution.*

**Thanks for the great support of Mr. Rob Farley for being with me in this journey** and also to all the SO members. This forum is really really great (:

Pls help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to login to your new db as your admin login and create a user for your new login. Then try connecting as the new login again.

Comment: Dear Sir,
I have success accomplished my work. But what I have done is that after I logged in to my SQL AZURE platform thru SSMs, first I created a database(say myFirstDB). Then I logged out. Again I connected and this time Under Options->Connect to Database->I typed myFirstDB and then connected. After that I created a table and inserted some values. Thanks for your great support with me for this journey.

Comment: Thank you very very much for helping me in doing the firewall setting. Now I am thinking why I missed that out?(:

1ce again, thanks for ur great support.

Comment: Terrific - I'm glad I could help.