# Azure connection string exception "network-related orinstance-specific error occurred"

Tags: azure, connection-string, azure-sql-database

When attempting to connect to SQL Azure with the following connection string

> Server=tcp:SERVER.database.windows.net,1433;Database=DBNAME;User ID=USER@SERVER;Password=PASSWORD;Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True

from a locally running ASP.NET MVC application I receive this exception:

> {"A network-related or
>   instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL
>   Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the
>   instance name is correct and that SQL
>   Server is configured to allow remote
>   connections. (provider: TCP Provider,
>   error: 0 - No such host is known.)"}

I realize this is a relatively generic error message.

In troubleshooting the problem I have opened inbound and outbound traffic through my Windows firewall on port 1433:

> netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name=”Open Port 80” dir=in action=allow protocol=TCP localport=80

I have configured the Azure firewall to accept connections from my IP address as well to "Allow other Windows Azure services to access this server." I *can* connect to the Azure database via SQL Server Management Studio 2008 R2. I *cannot* telnet to the database via

> telnet SERVER.database.windows.net 1433

Related Stack Overflow Questions:

- [Problem while connecting to cloud database](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1605303/61654)
- [SQL Azure : Connection to SQL Azure throws exception](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5066347/61654)

I feel like I must be overlooking something basic. Are there other troubleshooting steps I have missed?

Comment: You checked the information available on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg465380.aspx)?

Comment: @DOK I've looked through a lot of the information on MSDN, the article you are specifically referencing seems to be about Azure services and not SQL-Azure, am I missing something?

Comment: @Aaronontheweb tried switching to encrypted=False, didn't make a difference. :(

Comment: Do you have a proxy between you and web?  I have seen that some proxies block TCP traffic that is not running as the user.  Since web sites run as app pool identity, it gets blocked sometimes.

Comment: also, if you have a proxy, TCP proxy may have a different IP address than your HTTP proxy.  Make sure that SQL Azure has the correct IP address in its firewall

Comment: @lgorek I don't have a proxy configured and I "confirmed" that my internet provider is not shimming one in without my knowledge via the Lagado proxy test: http://www.lagado.com/proxy-test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Embarrassed to say that that this issue was caused because I fat fingered the server name. Apparently, I really am terrible at solitary programming these days. Thank you to all of the comments above which caused me to keep asking myself what am I missing.

Comment: It's always the server name, I faced the same issue few times. Since Azure db's have complex names, it can go wrong in many ways like mistyping, copying part of it etc.