# Can't connect to Azure DB using connection string from the portal

Tags: sql-server, azure, connection-string

I've copied the connection string provided by the portal (ADO). During my last visit , the site asked if I wished the firewall to be opened for a new IP and, naturally, I requested it to be so.

However, something seems to be wrong because the call using it results in the error messages:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.
>
> A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.

I'm not sure how to approach the problem, though. The connection string seems to be correct, as far my understanding goes. Perhaps it doesn't go far enough, though. Not an expert, precisely...

> Server=tcp:some.database.windows.net,1433;
> Database=Squicker;
> User ID=Chamster@some;Password=Hazaa;
> Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;
> Connection Timeout=30;

I've googled some guides and such but, apparently, I'm missing their point, because I can't spot any difference in approach between those and mine...

Comment: have you tried connecting from `ssms` using this connection string?

Comment: @MilenPavlov Good idea but no cookies. I get the same error message. The server name I'm entering is *tcp:f8goq0bvq7.database.windows.net,1433*. Is that the orrect syntax? I'm uncertain when it comes to the "*tcp*" and "*1433*" parts.

Comment: in my case worked without the `tcp:` part

Comment: @MilenPavlov Retested. Same misbehavior. I wonder if I can ping the DB server or something like that. Since it's in Azure, I feel a bit tied. Are you saying that you could access the DB using **the exact** server name I listed above? Perhaps it's the manager version? I'm on 2008 R2 right now...

Comment: used 2012 Express to test my db connection string. What if your ip address changed after you added the initial exception to the azure firewall?

Comment: Oh, that's a smart idea. Missed that. However, when trying to add the address I get "*The current IP address x.x.x.x already has a Windows Azure firewall rule. You should be able to connect to Windows Azure from this computer.*" What do you enter as server type?

Comment: Ok, maybe something on your end is stopping you (router/firewall)?

Comment: Possibly. I don't really know how to verify that, though. I'll try from another location later today but if that doesn't work, I guess Azure is not an option for this project, hehe. I'll install something locally (but I'm not admin on my computer, so that's a problem too). Very strict security policies.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6212073/azure-connection-string-exception-network-related-orinstance-specific-error-occ?rq=1

Comment: From the comments I strongly suspected something wrong on your end (proxy, firewall). You can open all IPs in SQL Azure firewall by adding `0.0.0.0 - 255.255.255.255`, try again, to identify if it's because of azure configuration, or your environment.

Comment: @l19 I'm not sure what I'm supposed to notice there. To my best understanding, the guy couldn't get it to work with any of the hints (one incorrect and one already included in his trouble-shooting). Then he realized that he spelled the name of the server incorrectly. Or did I misunderstood the material? Please explain.

Comment: @ShaunXu Possibly, yes. In that case, how do I verify that it's so? (I've run [Lagado](http://www.lagado.com/proxy-test). Is there anything else that can be done?) How do I remedy it? Is it a lost cause (I'm in a large organization that won't allow for much changes to the infrastructure nor settings)?

Comment: I think you have to ask the IT team of your organization to open 1433 port  to you.